# Witcher 2 bomb bugs

Tags: the-witcher-2

None of my bombs seem to be doing any damage. And neither is Geralt getting damaged by any traps in the forest! Is this a bug?

I saw that having more than 1 bomb in your inventory cures this problem. Weird. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug... at least the part with Geralt not taking damage from traps. I remember from my play-through that I got damage from traps in the forest.

The part with not giving damage with bombs may not be a bug. This depends on bomb type, enemy type, how well you hit, etc.